# Objective-C FontAwesome

Tags: objective-c, ios, font-awesome

I'm Attempting to get FontAwesome up and running on an iOS app and could use a little assistance. I have the following code for iOS:

```
UIBarButtonItem * viewDeckButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"\uf0c9"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self.viewDeckController
                                    action:@selector(toggleLeftView)];

NSDictionary * customTextAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:14.0],
                                  UITextAttributeFont,
                                  nil];

[viewDeckButton setTitleTextAttributes:customTextAttrs forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`@"\uf0c9"` corresponds to the css class, icon-reorder. The font appears to be installed on my system (see http://cl.ly/image/2F1x1z2H0i2N). I'm getting the standard box character, as if the font is not loaded (see http://madmonkdev.com/badchar.png).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the font file (.ttf) to your app's resource bundle and register the font in the Info.plist. Have you done these things?

Having the font installed on your system is irrelevant.

Comment: I've got some of the icons working but the currency ones aren't available and default to a wine glass... any idea why icon-dollar or icon-usd etc aren't available? they're just not there and i've included the fontaweseome-webfont.ttf straight from the font awesome site in my resource folder and registered it in the plist etc.

Comment: @towpse If you have a question, please post a question so it receives the proper attention.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting the unicode char to be correct.

I acheived it by downloading Fontforge (http://fontforge.org/) and finding the glyph in base10. Then accessing it in code via

```
unicode aChar = 65451
NSString *iconChar = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&aChar length:1];
```

Checkout this project for font examples: https://github.com/AlexDenisov/FontasticIcons

Also font names can differ from their file name. So a font file "font-awesome.ttf" may need to be accessed in code using "FontAwesome"